# How to remove milliseconds from utcnow() result in Azure data factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I want to pass a value for parameter usertime, the value should be like 2020-07-23T13:19:31Z , which will be used in my source connection url.

For this i supplied utcnow() function in the value tab. But i realized utcnow() will return the value as "2018-04-15T13:00:00.0000000Z"

To remove the millisecond part i have used the expression substring(utcnow(),1,20).
and also used expression formatDateTime('utcnow()', 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss').

Both my trails are useless where my expression returning error ass invalid parameter.

Could you please help me how can i supply the value 2020-07-23T13:19:31Z in Azure data factory datasource parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want utcNow inside quotes, here is an example from one of my pipelines using your format:

```
@formatDateTime(utcnow(), 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss')
```

which gives this result, setting a variable named x:

```
{
    "name": "x",
    "value": "2020-07-24T13:44:42Z"
}
```

Build it in 'Add dynamic content' as you can pick the functions and it will format properly if you aren't familiar.

Your substring won't work because it requires a string for the first parameter and utcnow is a timestamp.

Comment: HI Scott, Thank you for your help here.But i also want to have time  beside the date.
I dont know why it was not taking the value when i used the formatDateTime('utcnow()', 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss').

Comment: See my example, take utcnow() out of the single quotes.  I edited my answer to reflect the format you want.

Comment: below is the url that api expecting:
https://ma.api.1ws.com/V2/products/0MVXXX?app_id=af1f5123&access_mdm=computer&TIMESTAMP=2020-07-24T14%3A38%3A37Z&hash_code=tHL5X7BpywEe8mbpC1mTfCqQ0DkmhNYs1Zgg04t5Vko%3D

After V2 in url all are parameters which have static valua dn timestamp is only dynamic(it will only expect value from current time to -5minutes).

Url i am building in Azure:
https://ma.api.1ws.com/V2/products/0MVXXX?app_id=af1f5123&access_mdm=computer&TIMESTAMP=dataset().time&hash_code=tHL5X7BpywEe8mbpC1mTfCqQ0DkmhNYs1Zgg04t5Vko%3D

Comment: That is a different issue.  You aren't substituting the variable into the url properly, are you using concat and it looks like you need to encode the time part by putting %3A instead of the ':'.  It looks like you can use encodeUriComponent to take care of the encoding, I just have never used it.